# If a link title contains a URL, the link is rendered incorrectly in the chat transcript

Tags: bug, chat, hyperlinks, chat-transcript

**TL;DR:** If you use the `[text](URL)` syntax in chat and the `text` part contains a link, then this is rendered correctly in the chatroom, but not in the chat transcript.

I am aware that it is rather rare that somebody wants to use this, but probably it is still worth mentioning.

I stumbled upon this by accident, when I mentioned in some conversation in chat this post: [Is http://idownvotedbecau.se counter productive? Can it be better used?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/309507).

I used the syntax `[Is http://idownvotedbecau.se counter productive? Can it be better used?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/309507)`. This message displays correctly in the chat room. (So what I see there is "[Is http://idownvotedbecau.se counter productive? Can it be better used?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/309507)".)

However, in the transcript it looks differently - as you can see [here in the Sandbox](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/45381267#45381267). What I see in the sandbox looks like this: "[Is](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/309507) [idownvotedbecau.se](http://idownvotedbecau.se/) counter productive? Can it be better used?" <s>I.e., the same thing as if I posted only the title of the question in chat, not the link.</s> I.e., the first word "Is" contains the URL, and the then "idownvotedbecau.se" links to that particular website.