# Is there a sandbox chat room for testing the API?

Tags: support, chat, api

Right now I have one (1) reputation and I need 20 to be in a chat. How do I test the chat API? Do I need to get more upvotes to chat or is there a "sandbox" chat that does not need rep?

I know that the chat API is not formal and official and that is why I need to test it.

If there isn't a chat sandbox that doesn't require 20 rep, I will accept an answer saying so.

Comment: There is. See [What is the Chat Sandbox, and what do the commands there do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312490/what-is-the-chat-sandbox-and-what-do-the-commands-there-do). Though you'll need a moderator to invite you in as you don't have the required 20 rep.

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog I already know that. If there is no sandbox chat room that does not require rep, then I would accept an answer saying so. What you linked to does not solve my problem.

Comment: Note that here on Meta Stack Exchange, we close questions as duplicates if the answer to that question also answers this question. The purpose of this is to point users to the canonical information regarding the topic. See [this section of our FAQ on how Meta Stack Exchange works](/a/47635/377214) and the last section of [our FAQ on duplicate closures](/a/10844/377214).

Answer (score 0):

The [FAQ says it's always 20](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/faq). Ask or answer a question or do some needed edits to earn rep.

The [SE Sandbox](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1/sandbox), and the [SO Sandbox](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1/sandbox).

Many SE/SO Chat Libraries for our chat rooms are available at [StackApps](https://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/chat).